# Regex: get some groups

Tags: regex

I have some error message, eg.:

```
[ID: SD6G4D5G46S4G6SD4G] [API: POST /baz 403] Some message
[ID: SD6G4D5G47S4G6SD48] [API: GET /foo/bar 401] Some ERROR message 2
[ID: SD6G4D4G46S4G68D4G] [API: PUT /foo/bar 500] Some ERROR message 3
```

I want with a regex retrive the ID, the API and the message, eg.:

```
[ID: SD6G4D5G46S4G6SD4G] [API: POST /baz 403] Some message

ID = SD6G4D5G46S4G6SD4G
API = POST /baz 403
MESSAGE = Some message
```

I have tried to write, but don't works as expected

```
(\[([A-Z]+):\s?([^\]]+)\]\s?)(.*)
```

Any suggestions?

online demo: https://regex101.com/r/qQLaqg/1

Comment: What is your question? What regex flavor? What are you trying to do? What is the code you tried?

Comment: what?! is all into the question...

Comment: Oh, I see now. You could've been more clear though...

Comment: Could this help: `\[ID: ([A-Z\d]+)\]\s*\[API: (\w+).*?\].*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss a group, your last group matches `[API: POST /baz 403] Some message`

This does the job:

```
\[ID:\s*([^\]]+\])\s*\[API:\s*([^]]+)\]\s*(.*)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/qQLaqg/4)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below regex

```
\[\w*:\s(\w*)]\s\[\w*:\s([\w \/]*)\]\s(.*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzfRse/1)

Comment: or
^\[ID:([^\]]*)\].*?\[API:([^\]]*)\](.*)$